# How to modify an object regarless of inexistence value

Tags: javascript, graphql, javascript-objects

I'm currently learning Graphql and I'm messing around with it,

I've this mutation resolver where `links` is just an array of objects `links = [{ ... }]`

```js
Mutation : {
   update(parent, args) => {
      links[args.id] = {
         description: args.description,
         url: args.url,
      }
   }
}
```

In this current configuration if i update the `id=0` which contains the following:

```js
{
   id: 0,
   description: "test",
   url: "www.test.com",
}
```

The problem would be that if in the `args`parameter there is no `description`, then its value would be wiped out:

```
mutation {
  update(id:0, url:"hello.com") {
    url
  }
}
```

results in

```js
{
   id: 0,
   url: "hello.com"
}
```

---

Desired Behavior would be that if one of the two fields is not declared that would not affect its current value

#### What i tried:

```js
Mutation : {
   update(parent, args) => {
      links[args.id] = {
         description: (!!args.description ? void(0) : args.description ), // Check if description is null; if so, do nothing, else update the value
         url: args.url,
      }
   }
}
```

I've to clarify that, assigning `undefined` to `description` is not what i want, I'm looking for a way to implement this using a inline if, and avoid idempotency, to keep things clean, i don't want something like this:

```js
if (!!args.description)
   ...
else
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the spread operator:

```js
const links = [{
   id: 0,
   description: "test",
   url: "www.test.com",
}]

function update({id, ...args}) {
  links[id] = { ...links[id], ...args }
}

update({id: 0, url: 'www.wikipedia.org'})

console.log(links)
```